# Regression equation

Tags: regression

What would be my regression equation if I have a three level categorical value and a continuous variable?
This is how I re-coded my variables:City_d Capital_d Town_d.(recoded Town_d = 0)

**RECODE** Area (0=1) (ELSE=0) INTO Town_d.

**VARIABLE LABELS**  Town_d 'Town_d'.

**EXECUTE.**

**RECODE** Area (1=1) (ELSE=0) INTO City_d.

**VARIABLE LABELS**  City_d 'City_d'.

**EXECUTE.**

**RECODE** Area (2=1) (ELSE=0) INTO Capital_d.

**VARIABLE LABELS**  Capital_d 'Capital_d'.

**EXECUTE.**

And this is what I got in the Coefficients Table

constant:            3.843

City_d  :            -.900

Capital_d:           -1.498

High PoorH:           .425

High_PoorH_City_D:   -.316    **interaction term**

High_PoorH_Capital:  -.817    **interaction term**

The mean of PoorH is :.229 and the
SD for at high levels of PoorH is: 892

What would my regression equation be here?
Thank you

Comment: You've already listed your coefficients, why is the equation not known to you? (y=mx+c)?

Comment: I am just not just how to plug the numbers. I am new to Stats. We have a formula Ypred= b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X1X2 + but I don't know how to create my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to assume you built a linear regression model as follows:

```
Pred_ Target ~ City_d + Capital_d + High PoorH + High_PoorH_City_D + High_PoorH_Capital
```

With this model and the coefficients you've shown, your final equation will become:

```
Pred_target = (-.9 * City_d) + (-1.498 * Capital_d) + (.425 * High PoorH) + (-.316 * High_PoorH_City_D) + (-.817 * High_PoorH_Capital) + 3.843
```

Replace all the variable names, with the actual values from a record in your data.

Comment: Thank you very much Arun Jose! I wish I could email you. This is definitely helping.

Comment: Please mark as answered if this solves your problem